# what is the procedure to initialise an n by n boolean list in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, binary, boolean

What is the procedure to initialise an n by n boolean list in python ?

for eg: 5 by 5 boolean list

```
[
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

I am able to create it using following code , but type is showing as list not a boolean list in following code

```
   result_list = [[0]*n for _ in range(n)]
    
   print(type(result_list))
```

Comment: `0` is of type `int`. Use `False` if you want a type of `bool` instead, even though `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

Comment: Whatever you store in a list, `type(result_list)` always be `<class 'list'>`.
In python, you can store any type of data inside a python list but the type always will be `<class 'list'>`